# astropy.table.write() IOError: File exists:

Tags: python, astropy

I am using astropy.table.write(filename, path=run_dir) to write an astropy table to the file named dat.h5. But I am receiving the error that the file exists, which I've shown below with a pdb trace that it does not. What is going on?

```
(Pdb) run_dir
'/Users/ms/run0'

(Pdb) os.system("ls " + run_dir)
param.txt    temp_in.dat  temp_out.dat
0

(Pdb) os.path.exists(run_dir + '/dat.h5')
False

(Pdb) dat_cube.write('dat.h5', format='hdf5', path=run_dir)
*** IOError: File exists: dat.h5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `path` variable is meant to be a path *within* the hdf5 file (see http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.io.misc.hdf5.write_table_hdf5.html#astropy.io.misc.hdf5.write_table_hdf5; you can see in the [source](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/_modules/astropy/io/misc/hdf5.html#write_table_hdf5) that the path variable is not used for the `exists` check).  It is not a filesystem path, so your `os.path.exists` check seems to be looking in the wrong place.

So, (1) check `os.getcwd` and see if `dat.h5` exists there, and (2) try `dat_cube.write(os.path.join(runpath, 'dat.h5'), format='hdf5', path="mypath")`.

Comment: I do see that 'dat.h5' exists in the cwd. Using os.path.join but omitting path= still produces the same error. What should "runpath" and "mypath" be. Should "runpath" be the cwd? And "mypath"  where I want the file to be written?

Comment: mypath is *not* a file path, it's an internal path in the hdf5 file (or at least, that's how I read it).  `runpath` should be `cwd` in this case

Comment: Right. You're getting the error correctly because a file of that name already exists in your current working directory, which is what you write to any time you give just a filename. To overwrite it use the overwrite=True option to write(). To write somewhere else use write(os.path.join(path, filename)).

Comment: The working code is `dat_cube.write(run_dir + '/dat.h5', format='hdf5', path='data')`. Thanks keflavich.